# Superfluousness of ET-type $I$ for ES-equation (?)

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

> You may consult the following paper by Christian Elsholtz & Terence Tao: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/erdos-straus-conjecture/

A natural solution $\ (p\ x\ y\ z)\ $ of Erdös-Straus equation
 $$ \frac 4p = \frac 1x+\frac 1y+\frac 1z $$
is of ET-type $I$ if $\ x\ $, but not $\ y\ $ nor $\ z,\ $ is divisible by $\ p\ $.

A natural solution $\ (p\ x\ y\ z)\ $ of the same Erdös-Straus equation
is of ET-type $II$ if both $y$ and $z$, but not $x$, are divisible by $p$

> Are the ET-type $I$ solutions superfluos? -- i.e.

---

**QUESTION**:   Is every prime $p$ represented by an ET-type $I$ solution also represented by an ET-type $II$ as well?

---

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700130/parametric-solution-of-the-diophantine-equation-frac3n-sum-frac1a/1700195#1700195

Comment: @individ, over there they consider $\ \frac 3n = \ldots.\ $ (here, it's about $\ \frac 4n = \ldots\ $).

Comment: They consider the general case  $\frac{t}{q}$

Comment: @individ, thank you for your link. (If you see a direct connection of your post at StackExchange and my q. above about type I and type II, then, please, let me know).